# What does "W+1" mean with respect to the Pyro?

Tags: team-fortress-2, terminology, tf2-pyro

There's a more or less subtle reference I'm missing in comics [79](http://www.nerfnow.com/comic/79), [87](http://www.nerfnow.com/comic/87) and [131](http://www.nerfnow.com/comic/131) (pictured below) of [Nerf Now!](http://www.nerfnow.com/).

What is it about?

> [image: Comic pane from Nerf-Now. Heavy saves Pyro from wall of bullets, and quotes "W+1"]
>
> [...] *There are moments w + 1 is very effective and I dare to say, fun. However, there is a time and a place for everything, and going head-first on half-enemy team isn't one of these times.* [...]

Comment: May I suggest you describe the image as well, because else this question is going to do poorly on the search engines ;-)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I've not heard of W+1 specifically, but the more common W+M1 refers to holding <kbd>W</kbd> and the primary mouse button (typically with the primary weapon) to run forward spewing fire. They seem to mean the same thing according to the photo notes on [#79](http://nerfnow.com/comic/79/comments) and [#87](http://nerfnow.com/comic/87/comments), on the W+1 speech bubbles.

It's a common offensive strategy effective with ÜberCharges, but also one that's stereotypically associated with new/bad players (or players new to the Pyro).

You may hear W+M1 in other FPS games too.

Comment: I'm a WASD+M2 Pyro myself :)

Comment: @Bolt Uh, I hate the regular pyro gun, the backscratcher does much more damage and I don't air blast anyway... *[2014 badp disapproves of 2011 badp]*

Comment: @failbadp: I assume you mean the Backburner.

Comment: @Powerlord: Isn't the backscratcher a weapon too? I agree, he meant backburner, though that might be getting a 2x expensive airblast soon.

Comment: @Raven Dreamer: Yes, it is.

Comment: @RavenDream: 2.5x, and that was already added to the game.

Comment: @BotClock I prefer something like, WASD+M1+M2+3+M1+H -> fire + airblast, axtinguisher to finish and taunt on his dead corpse

Comment: @Drake: I light someone up then spend all my ammo airblasting. Just to annoy.

Comment: @Raven Yup! 50 ammo per airblast.

Comment: @fail - I wish my friends would play portal 2 less and TF2 more! (Or maybe I should play portal 2 more... one of those two...)

Answer (score 10):

It's a derogatory term used to insult Pyros by poking fun at the simple strategy of holding down forward (**W**), pressing fire (**M1**), and homing in on each target.

The problem with the term is that sometimes that's the best strategy in some situations.  Though it never hurts to include some dodging and back-blasting to back it up.

The finesse often comes in setting up for the W+M1.  Ambushes and back burner sneak attacks require great skill but they always end in **W+M1**.

**Update**:  The major exception to the W+M1 tactic is the many weapon combos attacks that the pryo has at her disposal.  Nonetheless, W+M1 will still give someone a decent shot at killing another player.

Comment: When I do run in with an uber, if I see a Soldier, Demo or level 3 sentry I'll time my airblasts too. I can defeat most Kritzes and Direct Hits at point blank while burning, as well as cause some other collateral damage.